# session in mvc model in guessing number game PHP

Tags: php, session, model-view-controller

the session after sending the form changes the number to another. Instead of the first one chosen by rand.

```
$correctNum = rand(1,5);
$_SESSION["correct"]=$correctNum;
```

```
if(!isset($correctNum)){
    $correctNum = rand(1,5);
    $_SESSION["correct"]=$correctNum;
}
```

```
if ($correctNum==|number from the form|){
    echo "Win";
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
}
```

Comment: I started the sessions in controller

Answer (score 0):

It is because you check if the variable `$correctNum` is empty, which it will be on page reload. You've to check if `$_SESSION["correct"]` is empty instead.